# Error 504 gateway time-out

Tags: yii2

При выгрузки с сайта данных в формате excel выскакивает такая ошибка Пробовал решать так:

```
<?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600); //3600 seconds = 60 minutes
       $gridColumns = [
       'order_number',
  [
```

и так

```
echo ExportMenu::widget([ 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider, 
'columns' => $gridColumns, 
'stream' => false, 
'streamAfterSave' => true, 
'deleteAfterSave' => true, 
'target' => '_blank', ]) ?>
```

Все равно 504

Comment: какой у вас веб сервер?

Comment: @L.Vadim  сервер Nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попрубуйте в  `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`
добавить строчку:

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
```

Comment: нет доступа к этому файлу. править могу в пределах проекта

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14290695/5910182